# Javascript key array by object and aggregate duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I retrieve a list of an order object that comes back as array [Orders], this list can be of any size. Each order object is structured as follows. I am trying to extract the customer from the order as essentially a key and group the orders by each customer.

```
order: {
 details: {
   price: ""
 }
 customer: {
   name: "blah blah"
   email: "blah@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

I need to figure out what the best way to group every order to a specific customer. Ensuring that if multiple orders come back for the same customer they are it ignores duplicates and still adds the orders to an array belonging to each customer. The ideal output would be

```
customer: {
  name: "Blah Blah",
  email: "blah@gmail.com",
  orders: [Orders]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What should the `orders` array contain, specifically?

Comment: OK. What have you tried? Because you say in your question that _you_ need to figure out the best way. So what way have you come up with. Maybe we can help with that.

Comment: What do you mean by "best way to group every order"?  We don't know your constraints.

Comment: So the orders array will contain an array of the order details basically everything that is in the order object posted above except the customer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu ive updated the explanation does it give a better explanation? What constraints are you needing, since this is pretty much object manipulation only.

Comment: You say it's an orders array, but you've provided an object in you code.  What's wrong with just a for loop to process the orders?

Comment: I was thinking a simpler process existed.

Comment: What properties are in the `customer` object on the orders? Can there be differences between two entries of the same customer? Stuff like a custom delivery address for an order? Or different addresses or email-adresses for different orders over time? Or does your backend ensure that these objects will always be identical?

Comment: Yes @thomas my backend ensures that the object properties are always identical.

Comment: @CLR45 Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably could be found by searching around stack overflow for how to group an array of items, and is probably duplicated...

But, something like this should work for you, assuming that you want to group customers by email.

```
var result = orders.reduce(customers, order => {
    // comparing customers by email
    var customer = customers.find(c => c.email === order.customer.email);

    if (!customer) {
        customer = {
            name: order.customer.name,
            email: order.customer.email,
            orders: [ order ]
        };
        // or use spread syntax, if you have that available
        // customer = { ...order.customer, orders: [ order ] }
        customers.push(customer);
    } else {
        customer.orders.push(order);
    }
}, []);
```